# CSS Grid Image padding issue

Tags: html, css

I have two column grid that has 0 padding on all sides and yet there's padding at the bottom of the image column. Please see the image:

[image]

Following is the css code for the above grid section:

```
.rack-info-container {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.8fr 3fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

As you can see padding is 0px. I have this issue only when I use a image on one of the columns. If I remove the image -- the padding is removed.

Following is the html code for the image you see on the left column:

```
<div><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0507/8623/8664/files/sherpa_crestone_4runner_roof_rack.webp?v=1672120213"></div>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Use devtools to recognize the issue. It can be happened because of many possible issues and yet we cannot help much if we don't see the actual code. Please provide a codepen.

Comment: Have you checked if the padding is applied from one of the elements on the right-side?

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet direct in your question and check that it shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think what's happening is your content is overflowing on the right side. So it's causing the gap beneath your image. You would need to remove padding on the right cell,  restrict/control content on the right, or allow scrolling for `overlfow-y`. I made a code pen to show an example: https://codepen.io/matt6frey/pen/OJwMvNr

Comment: Please could you create a runnable snippet in your question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I thought at first the problem was related to the gap being left for (potential) descenders, but I am unable to recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the image dimensions. Please check if the image dimensions matches with the container. You can use object-fit property as mentioned here for the img tag. [Object-fit examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)